# SAXParseException; Invalid encoding name "UTF8"

Tags: java, playframework, saxparseexception

I am using Play Framework 1.2.4 and trying to parse a SOAP response.

Response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
...
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I try to parse it with `play.libs.WS.HttpResponse.getXml()` I am getting a fatal error:

```
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Invalid encoding name "UTF8".
```

It is interesting that encoding is not **"UTF8"** it is **"UTF-8"**. So why I am getting this exception? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The missing '<' in the first line is a typo, right?

Comment: Yep it is copy paste error ;) actually it is correct in code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced same problem in my xmlrpc server application because of a non-standard client that sent UTF8.

As I found, it is xerces that raise that exception and my fix to bypass it was using EncodingMap class for registering UTF8 as UTF-8:

```
EncodingMap.putIANA2JavaMapping( "UTF8", "UTF8" );
EncodingMap.putJava2IANAMapping( "UTF8", "UTF8" );
```